# PyCharm is not doing code inspection on non-project files

Tags: python, pycharm, inspection

I'm working on a Python project in PyCharm and I wanted to edit a python script outside the project. 
PyCharm doesn't inspect the code and doesn't give any PEP8 violations.
Hoped that there would be a setting for that but couldn't find anything so far.

Does anyone know how to enable code inspection on non-project files in PyCharm?

[image]

Comment: Just drag & dropped a python script not part of my project into Pycharm 2016.1 (the tab is yellow, like your screenshot), the inspection did run. Even more so, it is actually complaining about PEP 8 :) Random guess, are you in power save mode maybe ?

Comment: @Arnaud P: No, Power save mode is not enabled. Could you try to write a script like in the screenshot? 
Does PyCharm throw "Unresolved reference" error? 
Because mine doesn't...

Comment: Tried, no 'unresolved reference' either. I checked the scope of this inspection, but it was already set to _all scopes_. I suppose Pycharm considers it doesn't know enough to complain about unresolved variables, since this file might be part of another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the problem (with 5.0.5 Pro Linux version).

The inspection is actually active and the PEP8 checks are all enabled, I even got a `blank line at end of file` flag raised, but not an `unresolved reference` one:

[image]

Looks like Arnaud P may be right, as the exact same file content in a project file raises the unresolved reference flags:

> I suppose Pycharm considers it doesn't know enough to complain about
>   unresolved variables, since this file might be part of another
>   project. – Arnaud P 22 mins ago

Confirmed by JetBrains:

> This is the answer I've got from them: "This is expected behavior,
>   this inspection is suspended if file is outside of current project.
>   PyCharm doesn't know configuration, source roots, etc of other
>   projects/other files." So I mark your suggestion as the accepted
>   answer. – Sinan Çetinkaya 5 mins ago

As a workaround you could have a (re-usable) project with one (or more) files in which you paste non-project file contents just for the purpose of running inspections.

Or just create a project for that file.

Comment: This is the answer I've got from them: "This is expected behavior, this inspection is suspended if file is outside of current project. 
PyCharm doesn't know configuration, source roots, etc of other projects/other files." So I mark your suggestion as the accepted answer.